# What is the limit for upstreams I can provide for Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a unique requirement where I need to use Nginx to reverse proxy to more than 1000 upstreams. Some of them are even load balanced. So basically I have around 5000 backend applications working on different ports on around 300 host systems.

I have two questions:

1. Can nginx support so many upstreams? Is there any limit or performance degradation in case I do that?
2. These 5000 backend applications are dynamic in nature & I need to keep on updating nginx configuration multiple times every minute. Is it safe to do so many reloads? Any better alternatives?

Comment: Reloading nginx once per minute is definitely bad idea. Why you would want that?

Comment: I need to route traffic to dynamic docker containers that'll have different IPs every time they come up & down. Any alternatives ?